# PHP wildcard for object key

Tags: php

I sometimes encounter and object like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
[batchcomplete] => 
[query] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pages] => stdClass Object
            (
                [48548] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [pageid] => 48548
                        [ns] => 0
                        [title] => Dopamine
```

That object key 48548 is gonna be different every time so I have no way of knowing what its value is. Lets say I need to get the title (Dopamine) in this object, I would need to do something like this:

```
$title = $object->query->page->{*WILDCARD*}->title;
```

But I haven't figured out a way to do this yet. Is there a way to skip an object key like this without having to find out the value of the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A numeric object property is not going to work.  Assuming there is only one, convert to an array and get the key:

```
$array = (array)$object->query->pages;
$title = $array[key($array)]->title;
```

Or just get the one element:

```
$title = current((array)$object->query->pages)->title;
```

If this is coming from JSON you might want to decode it as an array in the first place.  If not, then maybe this:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($oject), true);
```

For non-numeric properties this should work:

```
$var = key(get_object_vars($object->query->pages));
$title = $object->query->pages->$var->title;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just went with your approach. I've used CakePHP before and I remember it had all kinds of functions for working with arrays, one of them was a recursive array search tool. I wonder if theres a lightweight framework that includes various utilities like that.